# Spray how to Do some action after request has been completed

Tags: scala, spray

```
complete(OK,"some result")

doSomeStuff()
```

I need to do some action after the response has been send back.How it could be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can run that action on a separate thread using an `Actor` or a `Future` to release the handler thread so it can process other requests.

Usually you would reply [with](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) `202 Accepted` to indicate that processing is not complete yet.

Comment: complete(status, obj)
        sender ! message  

  This is what i have done now. but only concern of mine is, when  the the response  received by the requester it updates its state based on the response. But the next  action which I want to do is to access the  same requester and  I am expecting  it has the updated state.
 I am not sure  which action will be done first . If the  actor message is received before the response I have a inconsistency in the system.

Answer (score 0):

`complete` directive is just a shortcut for `ctx => ctx.complete` and spray routes are just a function from HttpRequest to Unit as `HttpRequest => Unit` so you can create a route like this:

```
val myRoute = get {
  path("resource") { ctx =>
    ctx.complete(OK, "some result")
    doSomeStuff()
  }
}
```

One important thing is `doSomeStuff()` function is executed on route handler actor and actor **won't handle** any other request while it is running. So it is wise to send some worker actor a message to do actual job if it is long running. For example:

```
val myRoute = get {
  path("resource") { ctx =>
    ctx.complete(OK, "some result")
    workerActor ! DoSomeStuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Won't this block the route until `doStuff` is complete. Route is handled by a single actor and other requests will queue up or get rejected if processing takes too long.

Comment: Yes, Indeed! It will block the actor who handles route. However implementation of `doSomeStuff()` is missing and it may not be long running job.